# Google Apps Script Update Compose Recipients

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, google-workspace-add-ons

This function is pretty straight forward, I just want to update the Draft Recipient email address. This format seems to match the documentation but it never works.

The error returned is:

> Exception: The parameters (String) don't match the method signature for CardService.UpdateDraftToRecipientsAction.addUpdateToRecipients

**The documentation is:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-to-recipients-action#addUpdateToRecipients(String)

Here's the function:

```
function toEmailDemo() {
    var response = CardService.newUpdateDraftActionResponseBuilder()
        .setUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction(CardService.newUpdateDraftToRecipientsAction()
            .addUpdateToRecipients('John Smith <john.smith@yahoo.com>'))
        .build();
    return response;

}
```

It should fill in the draft email with the "John Smith" address, but it never works.

**UPDATE**

using an array of emails does work, perhaps you just don't need to pass the name.

i.e.

```
['johnny.walker@gmail.com', 'jim.bean@gmail.com']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem is not the name, rather the fact that the method [addUpdateToRecipients](https://developers.google.cn/apps-script/reference/card-service/update-draft-to-recipients-action?hl=es_419#addUpdateToRecipients(String)) expects `String[]` as parameter

In other words, an array of strings rather than a single string.

If you want to add only one recipient, you should do it as following:

```js
.addUpdateToRecipients(['John Smith <john.smith@yahoo.com>']))
```